# Query a table from Firebase via NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table `users` in Firebase with these data

```
{
  "users" :
  [
   {"id": 1,
     "fcmToken" : "APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7hdiWY78iar8s:APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7h",
     "fName" : "John",
     "lName" : "Doe",
     "phone" : "9786770861"
   },
   {"id": 2,
     "fcmToken" : "APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7hdiWY78iar8s:APA91bHJAzXe384OEYvfk4bKsyS1NQvteph7DwG7JRIMm_HuXg8EeNllVrsSi0v9W_Gh95ezbOStp3ZWuWl0AzFKxMaCOjN81yiz7A5qhkONrd7lP2CTkUbFErw28r3ONTLvo8c8sO7h",
     "fName" : "Jane",
     "lName" : "Doe",
     "phone" : "6178779690"
   }

 ]
}
```

after import I get this

[image]

I followed this exact post from Firebase

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot

[image]

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require('/Users/john/Desktop/Apps/APNS/node/mhn-app-firebase-adminsdk-bs45c-5ac3770488.json');

var firebase = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://mhn-app.firebaseio.com"
});


var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
ref.once("value")
.then(function(snapshot) {

    var users =  snapshot.child("users").val();
    console.log(users);

});
```

I kept getting `null`

```
⚡️  node  node app.js                                                           
>>> Done                                                                       
null                                                                           



^C                                                                             
⚡️  node
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're querying to get the `/users` node, and then ask for the `users` child in there. There is no `/users/users`, so you get an empty result.

The solution is:

```
ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    var users = snapshot.val();
    console.log(users);
});
```

You'll note that in the example you followed, they're also **not** doing `snapshot.child('users/ada')` in the callback.